# what is this code commenting style found in ruby code

Tags: ruby

I recently opened up a git repository containing ruby code.
And I see this code commenting convention - What is it, and does 
it have a documentation ?

```
  # Test if the current request URL is canonical
  #
  # @return [Boolean]
  #
  # @api private
  def canonical_url?
    request.path == canonical_url
  end
```

Comment: check here, https://ruby.github.io/rdoc/

Comment: @ray Or maybe Yard: https://yardoc.org

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely yardoc per what mu said. You can see the documentation on the tags used below:

- [@api](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#api)
- [@return](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#return)